# LibreOffice Calc - How to recalculate using terminal command?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Recalculate
The title said it all. I have a Excel file with a lot of RANDBETWEEN() function. I wonder if I can regenerate the number without actually opening Libreoffice but using the terminal command?

Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: Can a CSV file have functions? https://dnimruoynepo.blogspot.com/2016/12/command-line-arguments-in-libreoffice.html may show you what is possible from the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RANDBETWEEN` will recalculate automatically when the file is open.  So create the following macro in My Macros, which simply saves and then quits.

```
Sub Recalculate()
   'ThisComponent.calculateAll()  ' Not needed
   ThisComponent.store()
   ThisComponent.close(True)
   dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
   dispatcher.executeDispatch(StarDesktop, ".uno:Quit", "", 0, Array())
End Sub
```

Then run the macro from the command line as described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7295/how-to-invoke-an-openoffice-macro-from-the-linux-command-line.

However, despite the `--invisible` flag, the LibreOffice window will still appear.  To keep it invisible, pass the filename as a parameter to the macro, and then call `loadComponentFromUrl`:  https://superuser.com/questions/1135850/how-do-i-run-a-libreoffice-macro-from-the-command-line-without-the-gui.