# How to force LibreOffice Calc to recalculate a spreadsheet from the command line?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

I want to be able to force recalculating a spreadsheet from the command line in LibreOffice Calc.

I believe this is possible but am having trouble figuring out a complete solution.  I found another answer that suggests using a Macro, but I can't figure out how to execute a multi-line macro from the command line since they seem to be invoked by name.

Does anyone have a working example they can share?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/871479/libreoffice-calc-how-to-recalculate-using-terminal-command is what you want. That URL points to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12202/10017 with the actual answer on how to do this.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks but I actually can't figure out what to do with this.  In the first answer it says here is a macro.  In the second answer is an example for OpenOffice, not Libreoffice and it says "macro:///" - what do I do with this?  How do I put the macro from the first one into macro:/// format?  Do I write it to a file and provide a URL?  If not, how do i encode a multi-line macro into a single-line string?